# Почему счетчик начинает работать только со 2 клика?

Tags: javascript

Пытался через return делать, тоже самое.

```js
const btn = document.createElement('button');

document.body.append(btn);

let count = 0;
btn.textContent = count;

function ttt() {
  btn.textContent = count++;
  // return count
}

// ttt()

btn.addEventListener('click', ttt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код работает с первого клика, только значение увеличивается ***после*** присвоения элементу. У вас постинкрементация, сделайте прединкрементацию

```js
const btn = document.createElement('button');

document.body.append(btn);

let count = 0;
btn.textContent = count;

function ttt() {
  btn.textContent = ++count;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', ttt)
```